# How to keep record for previous rows PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I have an issue

it's a carpooling table,
with id, driver_id, passenger_id and meeting_at (TIMESTAMP) as columns.

we want to add a field to be able to group passengers with the same shift.
That is, to know which are passenger trips should be grouped together because they correspond to the same driver trip.

For this, we consider that for a driver all the passenger trips within a 2H interval correspond to the same trip within the limit of 3 passengers simultaneously.

```
CREATE TABLE carpooling_proofs (
"id" UUID PRIMARY KEY,
"driver_id" UUID,
"passenger_id" UUID,
"meeting_at" TIMESTAMP
);
```

```
INSERT INTO carpooling_proofs
("id", "driver_id", "passenger_id", "meeting_at")
VALUES
('73b76183-51e2-489a-b45e-714db8f2e1ad', 'f7d65f90-e8ec-42d6-9bbf-4c8d6b2fbfde',
'94523464-df44-4646-85f0-14eb50e708b8', '2020-06-07 13:55:40'),
('154b1602-4755-4b39-9a16-5edda862e51d', 'f7d65f90-e8ec-42d6-9bbf-4c8d6b2fbfde',
'51bc563c-46d2-414f-86a7-7cf916bdd1bf', '2020-06-07 14:01:40'),
('a4a363a4-e27f-4411-940e-fc52740acd96', 'f7d65f90-e8ec-42d6-9bbf-4c8d6b2fbfde',
'35c8d21e-ba7d-46cc-b839-216ea7f98000', '2020-06-07 14:05:40'),
('846a831e-9800-4a36-9857-0191e53ae043', 'f7d65f90-e8ec-42d6-9bbf-4c8d6b2fbfde',
'94523464-df44-4646-85f0-14eb50e708b8', '2020-06-09T14:04:41'),
('e3ee74a1-8fc1-4bab-9d65-eeaab9b700a7', 'f7d65f90-e8ec-42d6-9bbf-4c8d6b2fbfde',
'94523464-df44-4646-85f0-14eb50e708b8', '2020-06-08 14:02:40'),
('4c46552a-b831-40fb-a7b7-4f33e5b75670', 'f7d65f90-e8ec-42d6-9bbf-4c8d6b2fbfde',
'51bc563c-46d2-414f-86a7-7cf916bdd1bf', '2020-06-08 14:04:40'),
('751fb939-f2c3-4539-879b-bb78d0f094b0', 'c5196b37-27f6-46ec-b930-1da27a1e65c6',
'35c8d21e-ba7d-46cc-b839-216ea7f98000', '2020-06-08 14:08:40'),
('bdbe0e4f-96d9-4710-a168-b445f8d9a96d', 'c5196b37-27f6-46ec-b930-1da27a1e65c6',
'cfa1f9f3-eeb5-4dd1-a235-abf57b93ef49', '2020-06-08 14:06:40');
```

it's about writing a query that can create a column named trip_id that takes the id of the first run as shown below :

```
+----+-----------+--------------+---------------------+---------+
| id | driver_id | passenger_id |     meeting_at      | trip_id |
+----+-----------+--------------+---------------------+---------+
|  1 |        d1 | p1           | 2020-06-07T13:55:40 |       1 |
|  2 |        d1 | p2           | 2020-06-07T14:01:40 |       1 |
|  3 |        d1 | p3           | 2020-06-07T14:05:40 |       1 |
|  4 |        d1 | p4           | 2020-06-08T14:02:40 |       4 |
|  5 |        d1 | p5           | 2020-06-08T14:04:40 |       4 |
|  6 |        d1 | p6           | 2020-06-09T14:04:41 |       6 |
|  7 |        d2 | p7           | 2020-06-08T14:08:40 |       7 |
|  8 |        d2 | p8           | 2020-06-08T14:06:40 |       7 |
+----+-----------+--------------+---------------------+---------+
```

What is the right way to do this?

Comment: Welcome to the SO Community. The community will help you with your issues, but there are certain expectations you need to satisfy. One of then being posting data and results as formatted text - **not images**.  See [Why no images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). See here to create nice [looking  text](https://senseful.github.io/text-table/) or even better a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13).

Comment: It would serve you well to take a few minuets on the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour/) and review [ask].